# How to fill multiple forms using single form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to build an online application where user can fill my another 2 websites suppose http://www.abc.html and http://xyz.html contact us form using my third website form suppose http://def.html.

Actually, when you fill the form in http://def.html then after clicking on submit button it should give fill the both form presented in another 2 websites.

I am not getting of how to do this? I have researched many times on Google but yet not get satisfied answers except that this could be done via java-script and URL. Here is the URL of what I get so far..

URL- http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-all-form-objects.phtml

I am new in web developing and trying to build this. Please suggest me how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: When the form is submitted, open the other two pages with the form values passed through a query string. Then on the pages, parse the queryString and update the form

Comment: @vihan1086 thanks for reply, can you share a sample code?

Comment: yeah, something like `http://abc.html?val1='foo'&val2='bar'` Using

Comment: OP might be usint POST, in which case it is probably not a good idea to put all the form values into the URL.

Comment: yes, but there are 2 problems:
1) How to send that 2 different websites pages?
2) How to click button on that webpages so that they data could save in database
@vihan1086

Comment: @Rohitz-zuststayhere you could POST the form using AJAX. Use `window.open()` to open two pages

Comment: @Mike, but there is no other option, i guess

Comment: This sounds like it would be better to use PHP to submit the forms on the other pages. Try looking into [curl()](http://php.net/curl).

Comment: @vihan1086 what about to save the data in database via clicking on their submit buttons?

Comment: @Rohitz-zuststayhere this can be done completely client-side, I would avoid storing the data on the server

Comment: @vihan1086  suppose i created a form on which after filling that form you will be redirect to google next step of singhup . How can I do this?

Comment: @Mike thanks for url, its similar but still not what i am looking for...

Comment: @Rohitz-zuststay if you don't own the result page(s), you can't inject your form values in them *(for obvious reasons)*.

Comment: @Rohitz-zuststayhere Why is it not what you are looking for?

Comment: @vihan1086 i got it.

Comment: dumb question but why would you need to fill out a `contact us` form on more than one site at a time?

Comment: @charlietfl It seems like a pretty non-dumb question to me.

Comment: thanks@Mike, yes its not, an if it is, then please share the source code for that @charlietfl

Comment: @Rohitz-zuststayhere code for what? I was asking why you need to send same data to multiple sites. If you need to administer multiple sites create an admin that pulls data in from all of them rather than duplicating same data

Comment: @charlietfl Because brother, I am not the administrator of those 2 websites. I just want that suppose if two different forms on 2 different domains asking for same questions like name, email address etc creating accounts then rather then filling those 2 forms we can create the single form that will send that to that 2 webpages and submit them. Its as easy as it seems...

Answer (score 2):

I would store them as arrays or strings , then use it for future purpose unless they are not different pages of websites , in that case you have to use cross-site in JSON .

Comment: I don't think you understood the question

Comment: yeah i know , i just thought it is the most logical step to store the info anyway unless it is not something like concurrent process or transaction ..

Comment: @RaminTaghizada how can can do this for 2 different domains?

Comment: and yeah , as it is related to cross-platform environment you have to use JSON , search in google for more info , i think it is helpful .

Comment: @RaminTaghizada not true that you must use json, can use CURL and POST between 2 servers